# Aquamacs web-mode

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, php-mode, html-mode

I am searching a mode for web editing (HTML/JS/PHP, CSS separately) in Aquamacs. Earlier in Cocoa Emacs I've been using web-mode.el, but in Aquamacs I'm getting

```
Symbol's function definition is void
```

error. What's wrong? With the same .emacs config Cocoa Emacs is fine.

The problem is I need a mode which can combine those three modes (the most important for me is syntax coloring) into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the last version available here ?
https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode